# Kubernetes node-node communication

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to understand the Kubernetes design on how/if worker nodes communicate with each other. I found documentation on the [node-master communication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication/) but nothing on node-node. I've understood that pods can communicate even if they are on different nodes unless a `NetworkPolicy` prevents this. What I'm wondering is if the information flow in the master-slave architecture is strictly between worker node and master or also between worker nodes.

**Question 1**: Do worker nodes communicate with each other or does that only occur between pods? Or rather, do the nodes communicate even if their pods do not?

**Question 2**: Say we have 2 worker nodes and that we have ssh:ed into one of the nodes, what information would be available about the other node or the master?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do worker nodes communicate with each other or does that only occur
>   between pods? Or rather, do the nodes communicate even if their pods
>   do not?

A worker node represents a collection of a few processes: `kubelet`, `kube-proxy`, and a container runtime (docker or rkt). If by communicate you are referring to sharing node state, health etc. as in a P2P system then **no**.

Pods communicate with pods (or services) and nodes are also able to reach pod and service ip addresses (this routing is handled by `kube-proxy` using `iptables`) and overlay networking.

However, in practice kubernetes relies on distributed KV store `etcd` for keeping system critical information. `etcd` may be deployed on the same nodes as the worker processes which requires node to node communication.

> Say we have 2 worker nodes and that we have ssh:ed into
>   one of the nodes, what information would be available about the other
>   node or the master?

There is no information kept about the other worker node or master node.
You could glean some information from the `kubelet` config files or see connection activity to the master node (`apiserver` component specifically) in the `kubelet` logs.

---

In general, the master node(s) run an `apiserver` pod which is the access point to the kubernetes cluster state (stored in `etcd`). Pods, `kubectl`, etc. use the `apiserver` to get information as required.

Answer (score 1):

I documented before that [two pods within the same node can communicate directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46537432/6309).

But between nodes, you need to go through a router/gateway, using a [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-proxy/) and a net filter.
See much more in "[how is cluster IP in kubernetes-aws configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104579/6309)".

In both cases, the master is not involved or referenced explicitly.