# The Kubernetes cluster deploy server cannot be accessed using the master IP address

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm a Kubernetes beginner. I have set up a cluster with one master and two worker nodes, ensuring that all pods are running successfully. I have deployed an Nginx demo and can access it successfully.

I have a questions:

1. Accessing Services in Kubernetes:

   **Issue**: When replicas not cluster number, After I use nodeport to expose ports, the ports can only be accessed through the node where the pod resides, and load balancing is not possible

Here is my yaml file：

```
# nginx-demo.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
    targetPort: my-nginx
    nodePort: 30222
  selector:
    app: my-nginx
```

my hosts

```
# 192.168.64.129
127.0.0.1 k8smaster
192.168.64.130 k8snode1
192.168.64.131 k8snode2
```

```
[root@k8snode1 ~]# kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE     SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   2d20h   <none>
my-nginx     NodePort    10.104.78.46    <none>        80:30222/TCP 10m app=my-nginx

# if pod on k8snode1
[root@k8snode1 ~]# curl k8smaster:30222  # Timeout
[root@k8snode1 ~]# curl k8snode1:30222  # Success
[root@k8snode1 ~]# curl k8snode2:30222   #Timeout
```

Comment: Could it be the problem that the `targetPort: ` section is missing in the `Service` configuration?

Comment: Link to the Service Kubernetes documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#field-spec-ports

Comment: I mean the `targetPort` (not the `nodePort`) field under the `spec.ports` section. Indeed, it is not necessary to add a node port because your Service type is the default `ClusterIP`.

Comment: I added it, but the result is the same

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I confused nodeport and targetPort, now I have fixed the problem and encountered a new problem

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly but would you like to communicate between node to node? There is a post that may help you find your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137728/kubernetes-node-node-communication

At a glance, you need to go through a gateway using `kube-proxy` to communicate between nodes.