# Exposing port range for Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application that I want to host in kubernetes cluster. This application can listen to multiple RTP streams on different ports in parallel. My question is: how can I expose this application for externally? I see that Service object exposes Deployments on certain port, but I need to expose it regardless the port.

Comment: A pretty good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338232/is-there-some-way-to-handle-sip-rtp-diameter-m3ua-traffic-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

According to github [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864), port ranges are not supported in the services yet

Thought, take a look at [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services). If you use it to expose your container  with selector , you will be able to connect to your container's IP on any port

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: nginx-headless-svc
  labels: 
    run: nginx
spec: 
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    run: nginx
```

And you get an endpoint

```
sukhoversha@sukhoversha:~/GCP$ kk get pod nginx-64f497f8fd-pvk4b -owide
NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE                                  NOMINATED NODE
nginx-64f497f8fd-pvk4b   2/2       Running   0          6d        10.20.0.10   gke-ic-1-default-pool-963dd3ea-365w   <none>
sukhoversha@sukhoversha:~/GCP$ kk get ep  nginx-headless-svc
NAME                 ENDPOINTS    AGE
nginx-headless-svc   10.20.0.10   1h
```